# Where does one go to find out the reasons for why a Meta Mathematics Page has been downvoted?

Tags: support, down-votes, meta

I have been trying to find out why a question I posted was closed. My understanding was to post on Meta Mathematics (which I did). This post was then heavily down-voted (link below).

Where does one go to find out the reasons why a Meta-Mathematics post was down-voted? is there a Meta Meta Mathematics community?

Also, when the voters don't provide any detail for why they downvoted, how exactly are people meant to learn what caused the down-vote?

Link: [Unsure over why Question was closed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32577/unsure-over-why-question-was-closed?noredirect=1#comment145769_32577)

Comment: up/down votes work differently on meta sites. On meta sites, an up/down vote is used by a voter to indicate whether he/she agree/disagree with a  post. There is no need for any reason for casting a vote.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks for the info. Unfortunately I'm left with more questions as I simply can't understand why someone would disagree with a quesiton?

Comment: To be honest, I am pushed away from the way you response to another user in the linked post (even calling them a moron). This gives the impression that you do not want discussion, but just a rant.

Comment: Related older post: [What do upvotes and downvotes mean on Meta?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/718) (Of course, since 2010 attitudes of the userbase might have changed a bit.)

Comment: Also, headlining your user profile with "So very glad I barely have to use this rats nest of a site" probably isn't a great way to get the people here to spend their time dealing with your questions and issues.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC your comment felt like dejavu and [sure enough](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31082/profile-unexpectedly-stripped-of-all-data)

Comment: @CalvinKhor: My rep's below 10k so I can't see that, and I feel like I don't need to know exactly what it said, but I am curious if it was the same user.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC The same user complained about something (else) and a comment pointed out exactly the same profile description. Actually that something else is not unrelated, allegedly an older account of OP was deleted, and allegedly not at OP’s instruction. So OP seems to have been here longer than current account suggests, so I don’t know how much could be gained from OP ‘lurking‘ more

Answer (score 5):

From [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta):

> voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.

The Help Center says it only applies to [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s, but [in practice it often carries over to other types of questions as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75049/295232). Whether that's a *good* practice is debatable: [A Proposal for More Constructive Downvoting on Meta: Express Disagreement by Answering the Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193884/295232).

In this case, I think it simply indicates people disagree with your opinion that the question on the main site lacked details. But it could also be that they think the Meta question isn't useful because it's obvious (to them) why the question is closed and it doesn't need further explanation on Meta.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will say, it seems to be an odd setup. When it comes to feedback, surely clarity is the best approach . For example, should I trust that your opinion is valid or not?

Comment: Yeah, it may seem odd, especially if you're new to Meta sites. I'm trying to back up my opinion with some references but I could be wrong indeed. It's hard to read people's minds...

Comment: It's analogous to receiving a mark for any assignment with no feedback or marking criteria sheet.

Comment: I can imagine, but requiring to leave a comment has its own problems: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325416/295232)

Comment: Fair enough. Appreciate the info.

Comment: "It's analogous to receiving a mark for any assignment with no feedback or marking criteria sheet." Except no-one here is being paid to be your teacher, and we all highly value our community here and its level of civility. You might find it useful to spend some more time "lurking", i.e. reading and watching how others behave here, before demanding it change to suit your needs.